# Why do I get BUILD SUCCESSFUL while I had an error?

Tags: jenkins, ant

I am experimenting with Jenkins and Ant. I would like to simply run my Makefile that does everything, the build and the tests.

I figured out that the best way is to use Ant because I become flexible with my build process similarly to `travis.yml`.

Unfortunately the compiler I am using only exists on Windows so I installed Jenkins on Windows. I wrote this `build.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Hello World Project" default="info">

   <target name="info">
      <echo>Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!</echo>
      <exec executable="make"/>
   </target>

</project>
```

And the output I get so far is this one:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test>exit 0 
[test] $ cmd.exe /C "ant.bat info && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\tools.jar
Buildfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test\build.xml

info:
     [echo] Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!
     [exec] rm -f test_*.s
     [exec] arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -O2 -Wall -S -c test.c -o test_gcc.s
     [exec] make: arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: Command not found
     [exec] make: *** [Makefile:9: test_gcc.s] Error 127
     [exec] Result: 2

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Why do I get a `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` status while I got an Error?

N.B. I know I have to configure my PATH to include the toolchain. I would like to first understand this inconsistency.

Comment: What kind of build are you using? And what steps exactly? I've tried to repro with an `ant.bat` that just `cd`s into a non-existing directory and the error level was propagated as expected.

Comment: I have absolutely no ideas. I just installed Jenkins on my Windows machine and setup a new project linked to my Git repo. It seems the `<exec executable="perl -e die"/>` will eventually build successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Ant's `exec` task does not fail the build when an error code is returned. However, this can simply be switched on with the `failonerror` attribute:

```
<exec executable="make" failonerror="true" />
```

Comment: [Docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html). This is something I'd never expect. +1